# comparison between actual value and value that user input in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have write this code to make comparison between actual value and value that user input. I have set the actual value in a table named Spec

```
sampleID Category WheatType Silo M_Min   M_Max  WG_Min  WG_Max
1001       1BK      AGP      1   25.00   27.00
1002       1BK      AGP      21                  25.00   28.00
```

this is code to compare the value

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Spec WHERE WheatType= '" & ddlType.SelectedValue & "' AND Category='1BK' AND Silo='" & txtSilo.Text & "'"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnnOLEDB)
cnnOLEDB.Open()
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While dr.Read()

    Try

        If txtHB43S.Text >= dr("M_Min").ToString() And txtHB43S.Text <= dr("M_Max").ToString() Then
            stsHB43S.Text = "Pass"

        ElseIf txtHB43S.Text <= dr("M_Min").ToString() And txtHB43S.Text >= dr("M_Max").ToString() Then
            stsHB43S.Text = "Failed"
            stsHB43S.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

        ElseIf txtHB43S.Text <> dr("M_Min").ToString() And txtHB43S.Text <> dr("M_Max").ToString() Then
            stsHB43S.Text = ""

        Else
            stsHB43S.Text = ""

        End If


        If txtGlutematic.Text >= dr("WG_Min").ToString() And txtGlutematic.Text <= dr("WG_Max").ToString() Then
            stsGluten.Text = "Pass"

        ElseIf txtGlutematic.Text <= dr("WG_Min").ToString() And txtGlutematic.Text >= dr("WG_Max").ToString() Then
            stsGluten.Text = "Failed"
            stsGluten.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

        ElseIf txtGlutematic.Text <> dr("WG_Min").ToString() And txtGlutematic.Text <> dr("WG_Max").ToString() Then
            stsGluten.Text = ""

        Else
            stsGluten.Text = ""

        End If
```

The problem is if I just input the value for `txtHB43S.Text = 25.00, Silo=1 and WheatType='AGP'`, the status will display `'Pass'` in `stsHB43S` but it in stsGluten it also display `'pass'`.

output

```
HB43s = 25.00 stsHB43S=Pass
Gluten =  -    stsGluten =Pass
```

can anyone help me

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: sorry, i'm not clear with your answer...could you explain

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different problems here.  First, you are doing an arithmetic comparison of strings.  You should parse them out to an appropriate numerical type before comparing them.  Second, you should validate all of your inputs to make sure they are as expected before processing on them.  The fact that someone could pass in a value that is passed directly to your SQL query means they have direct access to your SQL database.  Look up SQL injection.  Validating your inputs will allow you to catch when someone passes in a null and when someone passes in something non-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your `if` statements is incorrect. The first `else` can never be true, because of the `and`.

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
If txtHB43S.Text >= dr("M_Min").ToString() And txtHB43S.Text <= dr("M_Max").ToString() Then
  stsHB43S.Text = "Pass"
else
  stsGluten.Text = "Failed"
  stsGluten.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
  end if
```

(I'm not sure when or whether you want to assign stsGlutenText a value of "".)

Brian P has good advice. For example, an input value of "25aslduihhaljsdlsdaf" will pass unless you convert both values to a numeric value such as `double` before you compare (look up `ctype` and `isnumeric`). The database advice good security policy.

Comment: It think my code have SQL injection but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: You should use something like @silo instead of txtsilo.txt in your query, and assign it with something like this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@silo", txtsilo.txt)`. It's a good idea to put all user input into variable parameters like that.